# Angular 4 change route

Tags: angular

I am tring to move from one component to another using the angle router, but the following happens:

when I'm in 
`http://localhost:4200/#/home` 
and I execute the change of url to move to

```
http://localhost:4200/#/view
```

with

```
route.navigate(["view"]) /  routerLink="/view"
```

the url changes but returns again to home, but when I manually change the url to

```
http: // localhost: 4200 / # / view
```

it works perfectly.

What is happening?

I use the following code

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module';
import { ViewpostComponent } from './viewpost/viewpost.component';


export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'view', component: ViewpostComponent }
];

export const Rutas: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Comment: Instead of navigating to `["view"]`, have you tried `["/view"]`?

Comment: thanks for u reply @R.Richards, yes, I used that way to change the route, 
and it always happens the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of your routes matter. Change the sequence like this:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'view',
    component: ViewpostComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Also as suggested by Richards, if you're trying to navigate from your Component Class, use `this.route.navigate(['/view']);`

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sample-routing-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

['view'] and ['/view'] both work same
if it is not working would you please post the template code 
the order of route import matter and match
the intend of use router.navigate([]) is when you logic finish redirect the user to specific page if you call router.navigate([]) in you home component can you show us the code